# Illegal character in query at index , while inserting double quotes in a url

Tags: java, android, http-post

how do i resolve this error ?

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
String link="http://myurl.com/Acces/DEFAULT2.ASPX?+ivrsDetails.getAssetid()"+"\""+ivrsDetails.getTime();

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);
```

> Illegal character in query at index 62:
>   http://myurl.com/Acces/DEFAULT2.ASPX?+Details.getAssetid()"17:47:21

Comment: encode the url an try again

Comment: You have an unmatched quote here: `+"\""`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...You have inserted an unmatched quote in the url

```
"http://myurl.com/Acces/DEFAULT2.ASPX?+ivrsDetails.getAssetid()"+"\\"+ivrsDetails.getTime();
```

Comment: I like this answer better because it explains what the problem was

Comment: That again threw the same error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 62: http://myurl.com/Acces/DEFAULT2.ASPX?+ivrsDetails.getAssetid()\18:57:16

Answer (score 0):

try below code :-

```
String link="http://myurl.com/Acces/DEFAULT2.ASPX?+ivrsDetails.getAssetid()"+"\\"+ivrsDetails.getTime();
```

**we are using \ (backslash character) for reading special character after using \ (backslash character).**

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=96

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html

Comment: That again threw the same error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 62: http://myurl.com/Acces/DEFAULT2.ASPX?+ivrsDetails.getAssetid()\18:57:16

Answer (score 0):

I used url encode and it worked fine ....

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   String link="http://myurl.com/Acces/DEFAULT2.ASPX?+ivrsDetails.getAssetid()"+ URLEncoder.encode("\\")+ivrsDetails.getTime();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(link);
```

Is this a good way to make it work?